# CypressError cy.visit() failed trying to load https://example.cypress.io/todo

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, cypress

i created cypress project
for that i run `npm init -y` to generate package.json file then `npm i cypress` to create a cypress project.
then opened it via `npx cypress open`

[image]

here i'm getting this error `[20928:0420/171517.057:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.`

but the cypress has opened.
when i try to run the default test case `todo.spec.js`

i'm getting this error i searched about this error for a day. i didn't get any solution for this.

[image]

can anyone guide me how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried adding/creating the cypress project using `npm install cypress --save-dev` ?

Comment: yeah i tried the same. getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of a proxy issue.
in my organization, I should write the test cases only in the localhost/org., server.